# VS2013 miscellaneous issues

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

- Visual Studio 2013, Update 1 (which i believe is the latest stable
  version)
- Win 8 64 bit + all updates
- Addins installed:

  - Workflow Manager
  - Web Essentials
  - Visual Studio Extentions for Windows Library
  - Snippet Designer
  - Productivity Power Tools
  - NuGet Package Manager
  - Microsoft ASP .Net and Web tools
  - Jquery code snippets

I've been using VS2013 for a short while and have found some very irritating problems. Im not sure if i've missed something or something has changed for a reason, or even if i've installed an addon that is causing some of these issues.

1. F7 - i usually press F7 to change between an ASP .Net page and code behind. If in code behind and i press F7 it never works, but the other way around it does?
2. Added a Web user control in a C# project, created a button double clicked the button for it to write the event template code in code behind but instead it did it in the ASPX page?
3. Usually i create a New Web Site (note this is not creating a new project, this is when your in a project you right click and select Add New Web site) i add my Library projects and then i usually use the Attach Process to look for the site and attach to it to debug - the site is never listed for me to attach to?
4. Created a HTM file and added some HTML. Wanted to see the design side of things and no option to view the Design?

I have searched around but dont find others having similar issues so im not sure if ive done something/VS2013 is corrupt (although it is installed on a fresh new laptop) or whether this is the default and new behaviour.

Please note i dont want to repair the installation due to past experience so really want to see if anyone can help on the above issues before i do decide to reinstall as a last resort.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Shift + F7 will go to design view
2. Not sure
3. You need to attach to the server process (probably IIS express)
4. The new HTML editor does not support design view

Comment: Ref no 3 - had 2 IIS processes running and attached to both but the breakpoint didnt hit?

Comment: @Computer: Make sure you have symbols loaded for your project; check Debug, Modules.

Answer (score 1):

For #3 you need to the attach to the w3wp.exe process.

Comment: I have no w3wp.exe process running